# Show that for every $p \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a non-consistent numerical method of order $p$

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

To be honest, I don't really understand this exercise in the first place.

A numerical method is convergent only if it is consistent, so what is even the point of a non-consistent numerical method if it isn't convergent in the first place?

Anyways, how should I prove this? I thought about writing out:

$$r_k (h) = x(t_{k+1}) - x(t_k) - h \Psi_f (h, t_k, x_k, x_{k+1})$$

by expanding one of the components as a Taylor series (up to $p$ so we get the remainder $\mathcal{O}(h^{p+1})$)

But I don't think that's the way I should do the exercise. I think we should rather just find a neat example of a non-consistent $\Psi_f$, and not try to prove it by direct calculation?